# How can I get a count of timeframes in a list of Pandas Intervals which overlap?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60226735/how-to-count-overlapping-datetime-intervals-in-pandas) and am trying to figure out how to apply it to my situation.
I have an EXTREMELY large list of items which are organized by id, start, and stop times and I need to the count of seconds which everything overlaps by, then aggregate it all into a table for further analysis.  I am trying to use Pandas to do this, as it seems like it is definitely the right toolset, but I cannot find an efficient way to do it.  This is code which would work:

```
a = [list of start times]
b = [list of end times]
c = [list that is 6 Months worth of 1 second periods initialized to 0]
startDateOf_c = pd.to_datetime("date that is 6 months ago")
intervals = [pd.Interval(left = i, right = j, closed = "both") for i,j in zip(a,b)]
for v in interval:
    for i in range(v.length.seconds):
        c[(v.left - startDateOf_c)/np.timedelta64(1, 's') + i] += 1
```

This is O(N^2) for sure and I really do not want to deal with that on datasets that are literally millions of items long.  I have tried using a bunch of numpy tricks using filters and stuff, but it just didn't work out well.  I am trying to use Data Frames in Pandas, but something just isn't clicking into place for me.  I would like to be able to have a list of intervals and iterate over it for each second and get a count of all of the intervals to which that second belongs.  Ideally, I would be able to just sum up the intervals somehow to get the count.  I am thinking some sort of grouper function could do the trick, but the structure just is not making sense to me.

Comment: Have a look at https://piso.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Initially, here's the answer if largeness wasn't an issue:

```
import numpy as np

nd = np.array([
    [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1],
    [0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]
])
```

Each row represents an interval that is as long as the time frame in question. In my example that is 10 seconds - in your case 60x60x24x183 = 15.8M seconds.  With each second of the actual interval represented by a '1'.

Then get the totals for each second:

```
nd.sum(axis=0)
array([0, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

LARGE - I know.  To reduce memory you could use a boolean array.  Trues instead of 1's , etc.

```
nd = np.array([
    [False,True,True,True,False,False,False,False,False,False],
    [False,True,True,True,True,True,True,False,False,False],
    [False,False,False,False,False,False,False,True,True,True],
    [False,True,True,True,True,True,False,False,False,False],
    [False,False,False,True,True,True,False,False,False,False]
])

nd.sum(axis=0)
array([0, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Better but probably still too much memory.

The thing that might make this all feasible is if the intervals were such that they could be represented well using sparse arrays or matrices.  scipy offers that.  If your intervals are short (mostly zero or False) then sparse matrices could be the way to go.

```
from scipy import sparse

nsd = sparse.csr_matrix([
    [False,True,True,True,False,False,False,False,False,False],
    [False,True,True,True,True,True,True,False,False,False],
    [False,False,False,False,False,False,False,True,True,True],
    [False,True,True,True,True,True,False,False,False,False],
    [False,False,False,True,True,True,False,False,False,False]
])

nsd.sum(axis=0)
matrix([[0, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

Here's an example of one way to set up an interval row:

```
secs_dur = 10
sec_start = 2
sec_end = 4

sec_range = [False]*secs_dur
sec_range[sec_start:sec_end+1] = [True]*(sec_end-sec_start+1)
sec_range

[False, False, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Comment: Been reading over the methods you set out here and I'm not 100% sure that they will be viable for the problem.  The problem I am working to solve is that I have am counting the number of concurrently active units at every given timespan.  So I need to know if there are 30 active one second and 2 active the next.  If I am understanding your method, I would need a list of for every second to sum over to get the number of active units.

Comment: @Adalast You are correct.  That is my approach.  It will theoretically work but seems like it might not work from a practical point-of-view because of the memory footprint required.