# Pandas use start/end datetimes to find concurrent phone calls

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a set of phone call records with connect/disconnect times and I want to find out the concurrent number of calls for every second of the period of time in the data. Then I'd like to use that concurrent call data to get peak call times during the day.

I have a working example, but iterating with a timedelta of 1 second over a weeks worth of data is taking forever.

Example dataframe:

```
df
      dateTimeConnect  dateTimeDisconnect
0 2020-11-07 08:01:02 2020-11-07 08:02:39
1 2020-11-07 08:01:19 2020-11-07 08:02:08
2 2020-11-07 08:01:44 2020-11-07 08:02:05
3 2020-11-07 08:02:10 2020-11-07 08:03:30
4 2020-11-07 08:03:01 2020-11-07 08:04:15

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

Get the min and max times:

```py
startTime = df.dateTimeConnect.min()
loopTime = df.dateTimeConnect.min()
endTime = df.dateTimeDisconnect.max()
totalTime = df.dateTimeDisconnect.max() - df.dateTimeConnect.min()

print(f"{startTime=}")
print(f"{endTime=}")

startTime=Timestamp('2020-11-07 08:01:02')
endTime=Timestamp('2022-11-07 08:04:15')
```

Loop while loopTime is less then endTime, create new dataframe with a loc mask to get concurrent calls at that second, increase loopTime by 1 second.

```py
callsdf = pd.DataFrame()

while loopTime <= endTime:
    concurrent_calls = df.loc[(df['dateTimeConnect'] <= loopTime) & (df['dateTimeDisconnect'] > loopTime)].shape[0]
    print(f"{loopTime}", f"{concurrent_calls=}")
    callsdf = pd.concat([callsdf, pd.Series({"datetime": loopTime, "concurrent_calls": concurrent_calls}).to_frame().T])
    loopTime += timedelta(seconds=1)
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
               datetime concurrent_calls
0   2020-11-07 08:01:02                1
1   2020-11-07 08:01:03                1
2   2020-11-07 08:01:04                2
3   2020-11-07 08:01:05                2
4   2020-11-07 08:01:06                3
..                  ...              ...
189 2020-11-07 08:04:11                1
190 2020-11-07 08:04:12                1
191 2020-11-07 08:04:13                1
192 2020-11-07 08:04:14                1
193 2020-11-07 08:04:15                0
```

Is there a more efficient way this could be done with pandas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count overlapping datetime intervals in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60226735/how-to-count-overlapping-datetime-intervals-in-pandas)

Comment: Further add on on the comment, then I think you can get the max concurrent value, track the index of it, and you can get the start (index) and end datetime (index + 1) of the most concurrent time frame

Answer (score 0):

Use the linked method, and then do `asfreq`~

```
out = (df.melt(var_name='status',value_name='time')
   .sort_values('time')
   .assign(counter=lambda x: x.status.map({'dateTimeConnect': 1, 'dateTimeDisconnect': -1}).cumsum())
   .set_index('time')
   .asfreq('s', 'pad'))

print(out)
```

Output:

```
                                 status  counter
time
2020-11-07 08:01:02     dateTimeConnect        1
2020-11-07 08:01:03     dateTimeConnect        1
2020-11-07 08:01:04     dateTimeConnect        1
2020-11-07 08:01:05     dateTimeConnect        1
2020-11-07 08:01:06     dateTimeConnect        1
...                                 ...      ...
2020-11-07 08:04:11  dateTimeDisconnect        1
2020-11-07 08:04:12  dateTimeDisconnect        1
2020-11-07 08:04:13  dateTimeDisconnect        1
2020-11-07 08:04:14  dateTimeDisconnect        1
2020-11-07 08:04:15  dateTimeDisconnect        0

[194 rows x 2 columns]
```